# Struct member address after returning

Tags: c++, c++17

The following code emulates some code I'm working with. Basically `struct Foo` allocates an `std::vector` member (`d_vec`) and then defines some other member to be a pointer to the vector's contents (`d_buf`).

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

struct Foo
{
    Foo(std::size_t n)
        : d_vec(n, 0.)
        , d_buf(d_vec.data())
    {}

    std::vector<double> d_vec;
    double* d_buf;
};
```

Now, the following looks fine to me:

```
void buildAndUseFoo()
{
    Foo f{10};
    // do stuff with f.d_buf, it is safe
    // ...
}
```

What I am not sure about is this:

```
Foo buildAndReturnFoo()
{
    Foo f{10};
    return f;
}

void someMethod()
{
    auto f = buildAndReturnFoo();
    // is it safe to use f.d_buf?
    // ...
}
```

I wonder if the `d_vec`'s address could change from when it's created inside `buildAndReturnFoo()` to when it's used in `someMethod()`. Then if I attempted to dereference it, I would get undefined behavior.

Note: I have tested printing the addresses and they happened to be the same but I'd like to be sure this is guaranteed, and that I wasn't relying on "luck".

Note #2: I'm aware of safer approaches; I'm just looking to learn about this scenario.

Comment: what is the purpose of `d_buf`?

Comment: To be safe you need to write a copy constructor for `Foo` so that `d_buf` is updated when `d_vec` is copied (assignment operator too). But since `vector::data` is cheap to call why not just call it when you need it? Storing redundant information as you are is often a design flaw.

Comment: `delete f.d_buf;` Muhuhahahahahahahah! Burn, baby, BURN! Not that there's anything preventing `delete d_vec.data()`, but that would stand out more in a code review.

Comment: I should have noted that I was aware of alternatives, and that I just wanted to learn about this scenario. Thank you for the observations, though!

Answer (score 4):

Your struct is dangerous to copy or move in any kind of situation, not restricted to function returns.

When such a struct is copied/moved, the `d_buf` of the destination object still points to the original vector’s data. That’s almost certainly not what you intended. So you need to respect the spirit of the rule of 5[*] and implement a copy ctor, copy assignment operator, move ctor and move assignment operator that all do the right thing, i.e. update where `d_buf` points to. Or disable copy and/or move by `delete`ing those functions.

The alternative is to get rid of `d_buf`. Replace it with a member function `buffer()` that accesses the vector’s `data()` on the fly. Because getting that pointer is a cheap operation I’d lean towards this solution.

[*] The [rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) states that if you need to implement at least one of copy ctor, copy assignment, move ctor, move assignment or destructor, you need all five of them. Your struct doesn’t manage any resources explicitly, so you don’t need a destructor and technically it’s not the full Rule of 5. But its spirit still applies.

Comment: Good answer but this class is actually an exception to the rule of 5 because it does not need a destructor.

Comment: I'd move the getter function option to the top suggestion because it's going to be a lot easier to write, requires less code (and code that doesn't exist has no bugs), and won't be any slower once the optimizer's done with it.

Comment: It might be useful to mention "copy elision" in this answer. Odds are, that in the return case, no copying ever happens.

Comment: @user4581301 The OP was wondering how the struct behaves in its current form. Imo it’s fine to address that specific question first, even if it’s probably not the preferred solution for a real-word code base.

Comment: No worries. You've already got my upvote. I've just found that humans rarely read through the whole answer to find the best solution before rushing off to try the first one. I'll often start with the best solution and then explain what went wrong and lay out alternative solutions..

Answer (score 0):

The observed behavior may be caused by:

1. C++11 move semantic, if `vector` is move constructed by transferring data to the new one
2. C++17 Elision of copy/move operations, aka RVO/NRVO

For the first reason, tranferring data without reallocating is very likely to happen, but is not enforced by the standard.

For the second reason, it is also very likely to happen, even before C++17, but it is named variable, so does not fall into
*mandatory* elision of copy/move operations.

So the observed behavior is very likely in practice, but is not guaranteed.